# How to get lower resolution image in current clipboard after using macOS screen-capture shortcut?

Tags: macos, automator

I have set <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> to a keyboard shortcut to take a screenshot and save to clipboard, usually, I will paste this image for next usage.

But I want to lower the resolution of the image in the current clipboard because it's too big, how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Is it the resolution specifically you wish to be lower or are you looking for the size of the file it would create to be smaller?

Comment: In addition you what **CJK** asked in his comment, are you looking for an automated solution or is the answer given by **ankii** what your are looking for? If an automated solution, then please be explicit and specific about what you mean by "_But I want to lower the resolution of the image in the current clipboard because it's too big_".

Comment: hi,answer given by ankii is what I want, but I want an automation method , so I can paste a lower resolution image immediately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that Shortcuts is available on macOS, this can be done with a simple Shortcut:

1. Get Clipboard
2. Resize [Clipboard] to [Size] [600] x [Auto height]
3. Copy [Resized image] to clipboard

[image]

Comment: How to you trigger this?

Comment: I just run the shortcut, either from the Shortcuts app or have this shortcut pinned to the menubar.

Comment: Is it possible to also change the resolution (e.g. from 144 to 72 pixels per inch)?

Answer (score 1):

- With the image at Clipboard, you can open Preview.app, hit <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.
- Go to Tools menu > Adjust Size..., make modifications.
- Using the selection, cover the whole image, liberally. Don't worry if you've got lot of padding around it.

  [image]
- Hit <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and paste wherever you want.

---

"Export as..." also provides some options to downsize the image.

Comment: hi,is there any automation method to do this?

Comment: You can make a automator workflow to do so, but most of it is already present in the form of shortcuts like cmd + N, cmd + A, cmd + C. you can look into command Line tools that can do such stuff.. I think brew would have something for that.

Comment: there's no shortcut to adjust width and height

Comment: You can see the save as JPG which is a bit straightforward. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wm4b.png

Comment: I don't want to save a picture I want a lower res image in the clipboard(not data size, just resolution)

Comment: I used to think that they are perfectly synonymous. You may ask a new question about automating the method given in this answer or any other way that can be suitable, since this is not likely to get any more answers. Look into "imagemagick" and it can be put in an automator application as "do shell script" & accept files with drag  &drop

Answer (score 1):

I've had success by changing the type from .png to .jpg.

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture type jpg; killall SystemUIServer
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small app that can do this automatically. It's called **[Clop](https://lowtechguys.com/clop)** and it's completely free for clipboard image compressing.

As soon as you screenshot to clipboard, Clop optimizes the image to both `PNG` and `JPEG` and chooses the smallest one. It can also downscale to a lower resolution (`72 DPI`) if that's what you need:

[image: Clop downscale to 72 DPI setting]

By default, Macs with Retina screens use a `144 DPI` resolution for screenshots, which can be too much for most people's needs. `72 DPI` seems to be the standard for webpages, which is why macOS screenshots will look twice as big in web browsers.

*Disclaimer: the app has a paid upgrade but it's only needed for compressing screen recordings and image files. Clipboard image functions are free.*